# Lucene.net 2.9.4 SimpleFacetedSearch with numeric range on NumericField

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I put some fields like `manufacturer`, `group`, `description`, `num`.
SimpleFaceted works ok if I use query like `sometext*` with QueryParser.

Im trying to use `num:[100 TO 200]`, 
num is NumericField with SetIntValue(150).

I got nothing returned.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to search `num:[100 TO 200]` without using SimpleFacetedSearch? Do you get any results?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a normal query parser for numeric range queries.  However, assuming you know at query time which fields are numeric, it isn't too hard to derive a class from the Lucene query parser and create numeric range queries as necessary.

Support for numeric queries in the standard query parser looks like it should be available in Lucene.Net when a port of v3.4 is available.  (See [Java Lucene issue 1768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1768))

Good luck,

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer: the problem lies in the `QueryParser` not knowing that you're thinking of a numeric range query when you write `num:[100 TO 200]`. For the `QueryParser` it's all just strings (in version 2.9.* at least). If you want to do numeric range search you'll need to construct them by hand for now. Have a look at the `NumericRangeQuery` class with its static factory methods.